# How to skip some frames when tracking a marker?

Tags: tracking

I have some footage with tracking markers, that I set to use the affine motion model. Sadly, one of the markers goes out of frame just ever so slightly. When tracking, of course, Blender loses the track as soon as this happens. However, literally three frames later the marker re-enters the frame. I'm trying to figure out how to get Blender to pick up the track again for that frame. That way, I can do the tracking manually for the three frames where the marker is partially out of frame.

The "easy" solution would be to let Blender track until this frame, then manually do the tracking for the three offending frames, and then let Blender pick up from there. However, this doesn't seem ideal, because this creates a new keyframe that Blender will track from for the remainder of the video, instead of using the same keyframe from before. Especially because it's an affine track, it's going to be hard to precisely line up the track to minimize error.

What I think I need is a way to somehow just tell Blender somehow to "skip" the three offending frames and continue tracking. Or else, a way to tell Blender which keyframe to use as a base to track from. I cannot figure this out, either from clicking around in the UI, or from reading the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/movie_clip/tracking/clip/editing/track.html)... Is there any way to do this?

---

[image: The last frame before the marker leaves the image]
*The last frame before the marker leaves the image*

[image: Three frames later, the marker is back. It barely moved, so Blender's tracking should be able to find it... if only I could tell Blender to skip the three frames and keep tracking]
*Three frames later, the marker is back. It barely moved, so Blender's tracking should be able to find it... if only I could tell Blender to skip the three frames and keep tracking*

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Just select the marker and manually move it with `G` to the position where u expect the marker to be then you can continue tracking. It's all manual whenever blender loses track or incorrectly tracks.

Comment: Blender will not remember. The algo it uses is to continue tracking whatever was on the previous tracked marking. And since you lose tracking on the 3 frames you have to specify where the "previous" marking is so it can continue.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way to move a marker with G/R/S and *not* mark that frame as a keyframe it should track from?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, maybe can you add more screenshots of the issue?